# How can I set up starting page empty in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to set the starting page empty in my R shiny app. I mean the starting page shouldn't show anything except for the search bar. Then, once any value is plugged in the search bar, the result should show up. How can I achieve this?
My code is here:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
BB = read.table("first.csv", header = TRUE,sep = ";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "ciliogenics"),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(id = "SEARCH",
                  menuItem("SEARCH", tabName = "SEARCH"),
                  menuItem("Clinical Signs and Symptoms", tabName = "Clinical Signs and Symptoms"),
                  menuItem("Diseases", tabName = "Diseases"),
                  menuItem("Genes", tabName = "Genes"),
                  menuItem("Classifications and schemas", tabName = "Classification and schemas"),
                  menuItem("HELP", tabName = "HELP"),
                  menuItem("Related papers", tabName = "Related papers"),
                  menuItem("FAQs", tabName = "FAQs")
      )
    )),
    dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "SEARCH" ,
                                   fluidRow(column(width=6,box(DT::dataTableOutput('myTable'), width=NULL)),
                                            column(width=6,box(textOutput("myText"), width=NULL))))))
    
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    mytbl <- BB
    output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(mytbl,
                                                         rownames=FALSE)})
    output$myText <- renderText({ "The value entered in the seach box should appear here!" })
  }
)
```

Comment: The output is too long. Is there any way to do it without looking the output you mentioned? I am just searching for a change not to show the table while initializing?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own search function. Using `mtcars` dataset -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "ciliogenics"),
    dashboardSidebar(sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(id = "SEARCH",
                  menuItem("SEARCH", tabName = "SEARCH"),
                  menuItem("Clinical Signs and Symptoms", tabName = "Clinical Signs and Symptoms"),
                  menuItem("Diseases", tabName = "Diseases"),
                  menuItem("Genes", tabName = "Genes"),
                  menuItem("Classifications and schemas", tabName = "Classification and schemas"),
                  menuItem("HELP", tabName = "HELP"),
                  menuItem("Related papers", tabName = "Related papers"),
                  menuItem("FAQs", tabName = "FAQs")
      )
    )),
    dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "SEARCH" ,
                                   fluidRow(column(width=6,box(DT::dataTableOutput('myTable'), width=NULL)),
                                            column(width=6,box(textOutput("myText"), width=NULL))))))
    
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    rv <- reactiveValues(inds = 0, mytbl = mtcars)
    
    output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(rv$mytbl[rv$inds, ],rownames=FALSE, callback = JS(
      "table.on( 'search.dt', function () {",
      "Shiny.setInputValue( 'search', table.search() );",
      "} );"
    ))})
    output$myText <- renderText({paste0("Searching for ...", input$search)})
    
    observeEvent(input$search, {
      rv$inds <- which(rowSums(sapply(rv$mytbl, function(x) grepl(input$search, x))) > 0)
    })
  }
)
```